# datetimepicker using angular js in the script tag html

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

```html
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.startDate" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

in the JS file the below code but I am getting error

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
      time: "fa fa-clock-o",
      date: "fa fa-calendar",
      up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
      down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
    }
  });
});
```

in the console I am getting

> datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: if you don't know jQuery, but want to use its features like datepicker, then you should try [`ui.bootstrap` module](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) (used with Bootstrap 3), or [`ui-bootstrap4`](https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/)

Comment: no i want to use jquey only

Answer (score 0):

Do a console.log on jQuery() and to look at all its prototypes, then see if datetimepicker is there. You can even do this right on chrome dev tools or any other dev tools.

Comment: can we use by using Angular js do you have  any idea about this. i dont know jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should use the library you are getting this code from. 
I found out you probably found your code here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-docs
How to install the library can be found here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: i added all the dependencies  in the html

Comment: Are you sure they are added on the correct location? The error says that your code can't find the function. That probably means that the dependency is not accessible